# How to identify Lead source in META

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ads-api, facebook-ads

I'm new to META ad manager I'll planning to integrate leadgen form to webhook but I didn't get the lead source in webhook whether lead is coming from Facebook or Instagram.

Is there any way to identify the lead source?

I saw the webhook documentation but didn't find any property to get lead source.

Answer (score 0):

The platform doesn't provide that information. All of the leads essentially come through the same instant form whether delivered on Instagram or Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer but for anyone still looking for it :

You can call Facebook Graph API using leadgen id to retreieve a platform code ('ig', 'fb') :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{{ leadgen id here }}?fields=platform&access_token={{ your access token here }}
```